# Hibernate: save Map<String, Object> to RDBMs as serialized data

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping, rdbms

*How can I store schemaless data (`Map<String, Object> schemalessParams`) through Hibernate into RDBMs?*

Everything I need to do is to persist, read them once and forget, no querying by subfields or anything else. I suppose there should be a way to serialize `Map<String, Object>` and than deserialize it somehow. At least the same thing is done automatically by Quartz. Do you know how to do that with Hibernate annotations?

### My Entity

```
@Entity
public class MyParams implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "MY_PARAMS_SEQ", name = "MyParamsSeq", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "MyParamsSeq")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "job_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private MyJob job;

    // QUESTION: How can I store schemalessParams field if value can be one of:     
    // Long,String,Integer,Boolean, Map<Long,Boolean>, List<LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>> etc.
    private Map<String, Object> schemalessParams;
```

Comment: why not just serialize/deserialize rather than using of hibernate?

Comment: @yılmaz do you mean create another `class SchemalessParamsWrapper implements Serializable` which will know how to convert itself from/to `byte[] array`, and than make byte-arrayBLOB-filed inside `MyParams` e.g. `private byte[] schemalessParams`? I hope Hibernate knows how to do that without extra efforts

Comment: if data types inside of map are also serializable, then i think you can serialize it and save it to a file as byte array. Let getSchemalessParams() deserialize it and return as  Map<String, Object>

Comment: @yılmaz saving to a file looks like a vehicle, since I need fetch `schemalessParams` eagerly by `jobId` with Hibernate

Comment: can you give an example of fetching with jobId?

Comment: @yılmaz I do that through Spring JPA repository, but you can do that with SQL only. `public interface MyParamsRepository extends JpaRepository<MyParamsRepository, Long> { MyParams findByMyJob(MyJob job); }`

Comment: I'm sure an `AttributeConverter` wouldn't be hard to write ...

Comment: @NeilStockton wow, that looks like thing I was looking for!! Will `@Converter` annotation play good with `@Lob` annotation?

Comment: I'd expect a `@Lob` to do little more than define your schema, so ought to be fine